# How to create a dictionary from OS environment variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

There are environment variables set in the operating system (macos):

```
MYSQL_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MYSQL_DATABASE="invoice"
MYSQL_UID="dude"
MYSQL_PWD="pass1234"
```

I would like to build a list called `db_config` such that the end result will look like:

```
db_config = {'host':"127.0.0.1", 'database':"invoice", 'user':"dude",
             'password':"pass1234"}
```

(Note that the environment variable names differ from the keys in `db_config`.  `db_config` will be used to pass database connection credentials, and the keys **must** be those listed in the above `db_config`.)

I can "manually" set `db_config` using:

```
db_config={'host':os.environ['MYSQL_HOST'], 'database':os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
           'user':os.environ['MYSQL_UID'], 'password':os.environ['MYSQL_PWD']}
```

...but it seems like there should be a cleaner more pythonic way of doing this, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
config = {
    'host': 'MYSQL_HOST',
    'database': 'MYSQL_DATABASE',
    'user': 'MYSQL_UID',
    'password': 'MYSQL_PWD'
}
db_config = {k: os.environ.get(v) for k, v in config.items()}
```

Depending on how you want to treat items that aren't in `os.environ`, you can use a conditional dict comprehension to ignore them.

```
db_config = {k: os.environ.get(v) for k, v in config.items()
             if v in os.environ}
```

Comment: That is fantastic @Alexander!  I have a tough time with comprehensions, and this looks very clean!

Answer (score 3):

all ENV variable related to MYSQL in one dict

```
import os

keys = dict(os.environ).keys()

dic = {}
for key in keys:
    if 'MYSQL_' in key:
        dic.update({key.split('MYSQL_')[1]:os.environ.get(key)})

print(dic)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to rename `old_name` and `new_name` in the code below; and if you are sure that the environment variables will be present or require them to be available for your code to work correctly, you can remove the `if` section of the dictionary comprehension shown below:

```py
import os

transformations = (
    ('MYSQL_HOST', 'host'),
    ('MYSQL_DATABASE', 'database'),
    ('MYSQL_UID', 'user'),
    ('MYSQL_PWD', 'password')
)

db_config = {
    new_name: os.environ[old_name]
    for old_name, new_name in transformations
    if old_name in os.environ
}
```